# How to fill an int array with random values from a range with exactly one duplicate for each value?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, random, jframe

I am trying to create a memory match game using JFrame. I am using a folder that contains .png files (country flags) which will populate a String array using the following code:

```
public String[] listPngFiles(String filePath) {
    File[] fileReader = fileReader(filePath);
    String[] files = new String[fileReader.length];

    for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
        files[i] = "" + fileReader[i];

    arraySize = files.length;
    return files;
}

public File[] fileReader(String filePath) {
    File folder = new File(filePath);
    return folder.listFiles (new FilenameFilter() { 
        public boolean accept(File filePath, String filename)
        { return filename.endsWith(".png"); }
    });
}
```

The reason I am doing is because I want to create a dynamic JButton array that holds each flag in a random sequence, **twice**. The flags have to re-shuffled every time the program is executed.

This is the code I am currently working on:

```
int[] flags = new int[arraySize*2];

for (int i=0; i<flags.length; i++){
    flags[i] = -1; // -1 represents "no flag"

    for (int r=0; r<2; r++)
    {
        int pos=0;
        do
        {
            pos = randomize();
            flags[pos] = i; // put the flag into the card at the available position
            }
            while (flags[pos] != -1); // if card[pos] is not -1, it already has a flag in it
        }
    }
```

Your help on the matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Side note: dont use arrays, use ArrayList / List instead.

Comment: Use a `List`, and use `Collections.shuffle`.

Answer (score 1):

A optimal solution would be to:

Run a loop, add a number twice

Shuffle the array

```
public static List<Integer> shuffleImages(int numOfPhotos)
{
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfPhotos; ++i)
    {
     list.add(i);
     list.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    System.out.println(list);
    return list;
}
```

EveryTime you create a new game shuffle the list.

```
do
{
  List<Integer> list = shuffleImages(10);
  JButton []buttons = new JButton();// assuming this is your array of buttons
  for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
  {
    buttons[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(files[list.get(i)]));//set your background of your buttons
  }
  playGame();
}while();//exit conditon
```

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution. Works perfectly once I instantiate each element in the JButton array correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to achieve this using a list, a HashMap and two arrays.

1. Fill an array with random numbers without duplicates.
2. Create a second array twice the size of the first one.
3. Enter the values of the first array using the HashMap to test the duplicates.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Random r = new Random();
    int[] randoms = new int[5];
    List repeated = new ArrayList();
    int range = 5;

    // This will fill in a first array with unique randoms.
    for (int i = 0 ; i < randoms.length ; i++){
        int rand;
        do{
            rand = r.nextInt(range) + 1;
        }while(repeated.contains(rand));
        repeated.add(rand);
        randoms[i] = rand;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randoms)); // Prints : [2, 3, 5, 1, 4]

    // This will fill the second array with duplicates at random places.
    int[] finalArray = new int[randoms.length * 2];
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> intint = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < finalArray.length ; i++){
        int whichOne;
        do{
            whichOne = randoms[r.nextInt(randoms.length)];
            //Thread.sleep(1000);
        }while(intint.get(whichOne) != null && intint.get(whichOne) > 1);
        if (intint.containsKey(whichOne)) intint.replace(whichOne, 2);
        else intint.put(whichOne, 1);
        finalArray[i] = whichOne;
    }


    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalArray)); // Prints : [4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 5, 1, 1]

}
```